# Changing the size of text boxes in forms (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access

I created a form based on a query and want to customize the size of each text box. However, when I adjust the size of one it adjusts the size of all of them. Is there any way that I can make it stop doing that and just let me edit the size of each one individually?

Answer (score 2):

With the form in design mode, select the Arrange tab at the top, then click "remove" in the "Control Layout" pane to remove the selected textbox from the control group.